# Compile GLEW with CMake and Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2019, glew

I tried to compile (build) GLEW source code with CMake and Visual Studio 2019 for get binaries. In directory (disk) `C:\` I created folder `GL` and inside it, placed unzipped `glew-2.1.0`. In `C:\GL\`, I created the folder `build`. Because I found the file "CMakeLists.txt" in 3 folders,

1. C:\GL\glew-2.1.0\build\conan\test_package
2. C:\GL\glew-2.1.0\build\cmake
3. C:\GL\glew-2.1.0\build\cmake\testbuild

I tested all 3 paths in "Browse Source..." text box in CMake. In "Browse Build..." text box I pasted `C:/GL/build`.
In all 3 tests CMake responded:

```
"CMake Error: The source 
"C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build/cmake/CMakeLists.txt" 
does not match the source
"C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build/cmake/testbuild/CMakeLists.txt"
used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory."
```

that is "file CMakeLists.txt in 2nd path does not match file of same name in 3rd path".

Comment: Why aren't you using Visual Studio to build glew?

Comment: Dear fstam, please accept my thanks for your comment. I only know to build libraries source, with cmake and visual studio together. First step is processing it by CMake and second by  visual studio. Regards.

Comment: Look at this opensource project by TheCherno: https://github.com/TheCherno/Hazel You can find TheCherno on youtube, he shows you how to build glfw and glad using premake. I'm sure you can replace glad with glew and be on your way. You can also find him on youtube where he gives detailed instructions. I'm not in any way affiliated with TheCherno, just find it a good resource.

Comment: @Mr. fstam, please accept my many thanks for you sent me comment and for your advice. I'm satisfied with Mr. squareskittles's suggestions. Regards.

Comment: You might want to mark his answer as solution, for feature reference to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the top-level source directory on which CMake runs, you should first **delete** your CMake cache (**File** > **Delete Cache** in CMake GUI), and run CMake from scratch to avoid these errors.

Have you tried the CMake instructions on the GLEW Github [here](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew#using-cmake)? Try running these commands from the command line:

```
> cd C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build
> cmake ./cmake
```

Though this deviates from the typical out-of-source build CMake idiom, this is how GLEW intends the build system be created. So on your system:

- Source directory: `C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build/cmake`
- Build directory: `C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build`

Note, the GLEW build instructions warn about the use of CMake for building this repo:

> The cmake build is mostly contributer maintained. Due to the multitude of use cases this is maintained on a best effort basis. Pull requests are welcome.

Thus, you may have better luck following the typical Windows build approaches recommended [here](https://github.com/nigels-com/glew#windows).

Comment: Dear squareskittles, please accept my many thanks for you answered and that immediately. In C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build, cmake responses: CMake Error: The source directory "C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI., really this folder does not contain CMakeLists.txt file. In second path it responses: CMake Error: The source directory "cmake ./cmake" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI., really directory cmake ./cmake does not exist in glew-2.1.0. Regards.

Comment: @GeorgeTheodosiou The provided commands were intended to be run from the command line. If need to use CMake GUI, your *source* directory should be `C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build/cmake` and your *build* directory should be `C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build`. Hope this clarifies things!

Comment: Dear squareskittles, please accept my many many thanks for your helpful suggestion. What you hope works in my computer and O.S. (Windows 10). Also it works for any folder in binaries path C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/. For example C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/binaries. Regards.

Comment: Mr.  squareskittles, please accept my many thanks for your helpful edit (first delete your CMake cache (File > Delete Cache in CMake GUI),) in your answer. I tested it successfully. I did not try other suggestions (command line and Github's) for, your suggestions regarding CMake GUI are enough to me. Regards.

Comment: @GeorgeTheodosiou I expanded my answer to encompass my previous comment, including the source and build directories to use. I hope you got it working!

Comment: @ Mr.  squareskittles, yes, really I got it working. I say that in more details in my previous comment and in my edit in my answer. Many thanks. Regards.

Comment: @Kevin, Your answer is very helpful. I am getting the following error. Do you have any suggestion on fixing it?

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:95 (add_library):
  Cannot find source file:


    C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/include/GL/wglew.h
C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/src/glewinfo.c
C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build/visualinfo.rc

Answer (score 0):

According to Mr. squareskittles answer-comment to my comment to his answer, that I have tested successfully, correct answer is that the folder to accommodate binaries should be C:/GL/glew-2.1.0/build or any folder you have created in glew-2.1.0. It is peculiarity of glew though. With GLFW you can create accommodating binaries folder outside it. However according to Mr.squareskittles's edit in his answer which I have tested successfully, if you delete Cashe (in CMake GUI, click File > Delete Cashe) you can create accommodating binaries folder outside glew-2.1.0. Regards.